# What is the practical use of the %* modifier when using .bat files to run .py scripts?

Tags: python, batch-file

I've recently learned how to make a .bat file to execute a python script by double-clicking it. Assuming my script is named foo.py, the .bat file should be as follows:

```
python.exe C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Example\foo.py %*
```

What I'm having a hard time understanding is the final %* statement. Why exactly do I need it here? I tested the file without it and it ran just fine.

The answer "%* passes all arguments" is somewhat vague to me, I've been reading some theory about batch scripting and understood some uses of the modifier, but I just can't link it with the Python case. I'd be glad if someone could give me some examples that show the difference between running python `.bat` files with and without the %* in order for me to finally understand why it's really needed.

Comment: All the arguments to the *invocation of* the batch file are *forwarded* to the (Python) program. No theory required. “run_this.bat a b c d” would pass the 4 alphabet arguments to the (Python) program, or 0..N, as may be supplied. It only matters if the (Python) program uses the parameters. Python being the final called program/language is itself irrelevant..

Comment: You can have as many arguments as you wish. Limited by the 32K command line. However Batch only makes it easy to play with the first nine parameters (as `%0` is the batchfile and not a parameter). For more than nine you need to either use `shift` command (a hassle) or parse it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.cmd:

```
@echo off
echo batch-file_args: %*
python.exe foo.py %*
```

foo.py:

```python
import sys
print('python_args:', sys.argv[1:])
```

**Test command 1**:

> main.cmd

Output:

> batch-file_args:
>   python_args: []

No batch-file arguments passed so `%*` is undefined which is why you see nothing. The python script prints no arguments as no arguments were passed. `[]` is an empty list.

**Test command 2**:

> main.cmd 1 2 3 4

Output:

> batch-file_args: 1 2 3 4
>   python_args: ['1', '2', '3', '4']

`%*` is substituted and displays all batch-file arguments `1 2 3 4`.
The arguments are passed to the python script and it displays `['1', '2', '3', '4']`.

So, `%*` passed to the python script can work with both tests above.

---

> Why exactly do I need it here? I tested the file without it and it ran just fine.

`foo.py` that you have probably uses default values if arguments are not passed, which is why it does not complain.

Consider if the python script had a line such as `var = sys.argv[1]`. I will add it to the python code to test.

foo.py:

```python
import sys
print('python_args:', sys.argv[1:])
var = sys.argv[1]
```

**Test command 3**:

> main.cmd

Output:

> ```
> batch-file_args:
> python_args: []
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "foo.py", line 3, in <module>
>     var = sys.argv[1]
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Ouch, it complains with an IndexError. `%*` can be important as the Traceback indicates. No arguments passed would be similar to removing `%*` from the batch-file.